# Proving that at least half of all words with length bigger than $n$ are not compressible.

Tags: combinatorics, random, kolmogorov-complexity, compression

We say that a word is not compressible, if it's Kolmogorov-Complexity is bigger than the length of the word. We know that for every natural number $n$, we have at least one word which is not compressible. How can I now show that at least half of all words over$\{0,1\}^{\geq n}$ are not compressible?

Aren't there infinite many words of length bigger than $n$? I don't understand help!

Comment: Perhaps you should instead show that for every $n$, at least half of all words with length *at most* $n$ are not compressible.

Comment: Yes but i somehow cant get any further than that. Can you please help?

Comment: I mean to say that you're right, the "bigger than $n$" version of the question doesn't make sense, and probably the "at most $n$" version is the right one.

Comment: I think for bigger than n you can show that for every length $n+k$ at least half of them are not compressible

Comment: You have $2^{n+k}$ total words for every length $n+k$ . Now we count the number of nonempty bitstrings with $k(x) < n+k$ which is $2^{n+k} -2$. If we subtract this from the total, we get that at least half is not compressible.